go-swagger generated swagger UI gets CORS error even if I already handled it
After some research and testing, I still can't figure out why the swagger UI generated by go-swagger is saying my API still has a CORS error even if I already handled it. I'm not sure if it's an important info, but I wrote my API manually and it's not generated by swagger. I implemented swagger quite late in my development.
Here's what my CORS middle ware looks like:
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Printf("Received %s request for %s\n", c.Request.Method, c.Request.URL.Path)

        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With, access_token")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            fmt.Println("Handling OPTIONS request")
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

And here's a sample go-swagger API documentation I made:
// Package routes BARACO API.
//
//  Schemes: https
//  BasePath: /
//  Version: 1.0.0
//  Host: localhost:2443
//
//  Consumes:
//  - application/json
//
//  Produces:
//  - application/json
//
// swagger:meta
package api_docs

import "go_baraco_server/cmd/commons/models"

// swagger:parameters GetUserType
type UserTypeIDParam struct {
    // The ID of the user
    //
    // in: path
    // required: true
    ID string `json:"id"`
}

// swagger:route GET /user/{id} userTypes GetUserType
//
// GetUserType returns a userType by its ID.
//
// Responses:
//
//  200: userTypeResponse
//  400: errorResponse
func GetUserType() {}

// swagger:route GET /user_types userTypes GetUserTypes
//
// GetUserTypes returns all userTypes.
//
// Responses:
//
//  200: userTypesResponse
//  400: errorResponse
func GetUserTypes() {}

// A UserTypeResponse model
//
// swagger:response userTypeResponse
type UserTypeResponse struct {
    // The user type data
    //
    // in: body
    Item models.UserType `json:"user_type"`
}

// A AICsResponse model
//
// swagger:response userTypesResponse
type UserTypesResponse struct {
    // The user type data
    //
    // in: body
    Items []models.UserType `json:"user_types"`
}

type MinifiedUserType struct {
    // example: 355622b7-7693-4205-9b9b-86ea9313b525
    ID string `json:"id"`
    // example: Farmer
    DisplayName string `json:"display_name"`
}

And here's what the request made by the swagger UI looks like:

UPDATE:
I'm not too sure if this is the swagger handler @hmmftg was looking for, but here's how I implemented by CORS middleware.
// in some gin helper module
func StartClient(conn *grpc.ClientConn) *gin.Engine {
    ginGine := gin.Default()
    ginGine.Use(CORSMiddleware())
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    //tons of api endpoint handlers
    
    //tons of StaticFS

    return ginGine
}

//in main.go
finalGin := handlers.StartClient(conn)

err := finalGin.RunTLS(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", cmmHelpers.GetConfig("HTTPS_PORT")), certFile, keyFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to start server: %v", err)
}


Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is not allowed in combination with credentials, see here.

This question is similar to: CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Doesn't seem like setting Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to false fixed the issue

If the request needs credentials, that can't be the solution. Use a concrete origin instead of *.

That particular request I made with the swagger UI doesn't need any credentials, and even if I made the origin localhost, the request still failed

hi, can you put your swagger handler code here? does your swagger handler has cors middleware?

hi @hmmftg, I added some info on my question, not too sure if that's what you meant by swagger handler
